# Serialize function in PHP

Tags: php, serialization, get, query-string

I'm trying to serialize an array in PHP in a URL and then get it back using $_GET but my results aren't matching.

I'm doing it like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'Josh',
    'age' => '12',
);

echo 'www.someurl.com/page.php?'.serialize($arr);
```

then

```
var_dump($_GET);
//array(1) { ["a:2:{s:4:"name";s:4:"Josh";s:3:"age";s:2:"12";}"]=> string(0) "" }
```

but I'm not getting the same result as

```
var_dump($arr);
//array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Josh" ["age"]=> string(2) "12" }
```

What am I doing wrong, or how should I approach this?

Comment: You don't understand what serialization does. What are you trying to accomplish? json_encode() sounds like what you are after, maybe

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'Josh',
    'age' => '12',
);

echo 'www.someurl.com/page.php?'.http_build_query($arr);
// www.someurl.com/page.php?name=Josh&age=12
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is a serialized string, either you should `unserialize` it or `serialize` your `$arr`